# Determine foreign key relationships before DELETE

Tags: symfony, foreign-keys

I have a lot of relationships in my model and I have noticed that quite reguarly if I try and delete a model (I have set up various UI screens to do this) it fails due to another table referencing that record.

Is it possible for me to know in advance using a Symfony function whether there are any potential Foreign Key violations? Then I can interrupt the delete process and display a nice error or message or something.

Or if anyone can think of any alternative ways to do this I'm definitely open to ideas.

Answer (score 1):

In our project at the Department of Software Engineering we check the FK violations. In the controller we have set up a private function that checks the given entity for FK violations, and if this function succeed we can try to delete the entity.

The function itself is not doing too much, just go through the entity relations, and check if any referenced entity exists. If yes, they should be removed before deletion.

If you want to delete the referenced entites as well you can set a cascade to the relations as well:

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity", cascade={"remove"})
```